# EntityFrameworkCore 3 prevents building - Xamarin.iOS, native linking error

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, entity-framework-core

I am building a Xamarin.iOS application using EFCore 3.0 and SQLite.
When I try to run a simple [demo project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/files/3680229/TestEFC3XamarinApp.zip), I alwyas get 4 native linking errors:

> TestEFC3XamarinApp.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sqlite3_key_v2. This symbol was referenced by the managed member SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_internal/NativeMethods.sqlite3_key_v2. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked. (MT5214) (TestEFC3XamarinApp.iOS)
>
> TestEFC3XamarinApp.iOS/clang: Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (TestEFC3XamarinApp.iOS)
>
> TestEFC3XamarinApp.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sqlite3_rekey_v2. This symbol was referenced by the managed member SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_internal/NativeMethods.sqlite3_rekey_v2. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked. (MT5214) (TestEFC3XamarinApp.iOS)
>
> TestEFC3XamarinApp.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202) (TestEFC3XamarinApp.iOS)

#### I run these latest softwares

VS2019 16.3.4, Xamarin.iOS 13.4.0.2, Xcode 11.1, iOS 13.1 (Simulator), EFCore 3.0

#### I've already tried

1. deleting bin and obj folders and rebuild solution
2. deleting xamarin build cache on Mac (~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/build/*)
3. **--registrar:dynamic** and **-gcc_flags additional -dead_strip** additional mtouch arguments
4. reinstalling Xcode

The issue can be found at the xamarin-macios github page [(link)](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7153) but it hasn't been solved.
Do you have any idea how to fix for this? It would be great, because I'm stuck on this problem for days.